# Function Pointer Overloading Error?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have the following definitions and prototypes (which are member functions of a class) with which I basically try to use function pointers to pass a different type of strategy to the divideQuery method:

```
typedef vector<ConstraintManager> (*strategyType1)(const Query&);
typedef vector<ConstraintManager> (*strategyType2)(const Query&, int);

vector<ConstraintManager> divideQuery (strategyType1 s, const Query& query);
vector<ConstraintManager> divideQuery (strategyType2 s, const Query& query, int parts);

vector<ConstraintManager> divideByHalf(const Query& query);
vector<ConstraintManager> divideRandom(const Query& query);
vector<ConstraintManager> divideByN(const Query& query, int n);
```

However when I try to call (`query` parameter is passed from the wrapping function):

```
vector<ConstraintManager> result =  divideQuery(divideRandom, query);
```

It fails with the error message:

```
DividingSolver.cpp:200:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘DividingSolver::divideQuery(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const klee::Query&)’
DividingSolver.cpp:82:27: note: candidates are: std::vector<klee::ConstraintManager>   DividingSolver::divideQuery(std::vector<klee::ConstraintManager> (*)(const klee::Query&),  const klee::Query&)
DividingSolver.cpp:87:27: note: std::vector<klee::ConstraintManager>     DividingSolver::divideQuery(std::vector<klee::ConstraintManager> (*)(const klee::Query&, int), const klee::Query&, int)
```

As far as I read from the web it seems like an overloading error (or maybe something else) but in any case I am not quite sure what exactly is wrong. Any hints/explanations is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: The error you're getting seems like the one you'd get if there were multiple `divideRandom` functions (that is, the name `divideRandom` was overloaded).  Are you sure that you only have one implementation?

Comment: I added `#include <vector>
using std::vector;

struct Query {} query;
struct ConstraintManager {};` and it compiled for me. (gcc 4.7.?)

Comment: Are the `divideXXX` member functions of a class?

Comment: This isn't by any chance an issue with something not being #included or using'd?  It says "unresolved overloaded function type", which implies it doesn't recognize your typedef as a function pointer, or rather that it does, but doesn't understand the signature.

Comment: @dribeas: Based on the error message, yes they are.

Comment: @CharlesBailey I just checked and all the header files for those structs are already included (in addition to vector and std::vector) so not sure how it worked for you

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas yes they are as Ben mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a non-static member function does not have the same signature as a free function. In particular it has a *hidden* `this` pointer. Now what you have is a call to `divideQuery` where the first argument is a pointer to member function, but there is no overload that takes pointer to member function, so the compiler bails out with an error message.

If the functions do not use the state from the class, you can make them `static`, that will remove the implicit `this` and it should work. Another option is actually using pointers to member in the `divideQuery` interface. The third option would be using a higher level construct, like `std::function<>` (or `boost::function<>`) for the function argument, and then using `std::bind` (`boost::bind`) to bind the `this` argument.

Comment: @CharlesBailey It's a member function and the question is edited accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Make `divideRandom` static, then it will be compatible with a normal function pointer.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: the question is missing the important point that these are all member functions.